# Xpath 'instance of' not working in solr xslt

Tags: xslt, xpath, solr

I want use xslt in solr to output result in json without specific solr attributes.

```
    {
      "techproducts": [
         {
            "id": "GB18030TEST",
            "price": "0.0"
         },
         {
            "id": "SOLR1000",
            "price": "0.0"
         },
         {
            "id": "UTF8TEST",
            "price": "0.0"
         }
      ],
      "paging": {
        "count": 3
      }
    }
```

The test of type of field (numeric or boolean) `test=". instance of xs:integer"` in order to add or not quotes **do not work** and generate a 500 error.

```
http://localhost:8090/solr/techproducts/select?q=*&fq=price:0&fl=id,price&wt=xslt&tr=json_paginate.xsl

 Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: solrres:/xslt/json_paginate.xsl: line 37: Attribut 'test' obligatoire manquant.
```

**Any suggestions?**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="no" media-type="application/json"/>

    <xsl:template match='/'>
        <xsl:text>{"techproducts":[</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="response/result/doc"/>
        <xsl:text>],</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>"paging":{"count":</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="response/result/@numFound"/><xsl:text>}}</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template> 

  <xsl:template match="doc"> 
    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
    <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
       </xsl:if>

    <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:with-param name="pos"><xsl:value-of select="$pos"/></xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="doc/*">
    <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
       </xsl:if>
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@name"/><xsl:text>":</xsl:text>

    <xsl:choose>
        <!-- if integer, do not add quotes -->
        <xsl:when test=". instance of xs:integer">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:when>
        <!-- if boolean, do not add quotes -->
        <xsl:when test=". instance of xs:boolean">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>"</xsl:text>          
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**To solve the problem :** 
I have upgraded xslt version in solr `http://wiki.apache.org/solr/XsltResponseWriter` and used

```
<xsl:choose>
    <!-- if decimal, do not add quotes -->
    <xsl:when test=". castable as xs:decimal">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:when>
    <!-- if boolean, do not add quotes -->
    <xsl:when test=". castable as xs:boolean">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>"</xsl:text>          
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: do solr use xslt-2.0? try having this `<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:version')"/> ` to find out.

Comment: I think i don't use xslt-2.0 because `<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:version')"/>` do not send anything. I use solr 5.1.

Comment: your stylesheet says `version="2.0"`, so your processor should use xslt-2.0

Comment: @clood "*<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:version')"/> do not send anything.*" Are you sure about this? -- In any case, you cannot determine the type of a node in the source XML document, unless the document has a schema and you are using a schema-aware processor.

Comment: @clood, I have provided a short, simple and efficient XSLT 1.0 - only code that has the intended behavior of your XSLT 2.0 code. Do note, that even if you had an XSLT 2.0 processor, your code doesn't produce the wanted result. Tip: you need to replace `instance of` with `castable as`  :)

Comment: @michael.hor257k, you were right,<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:version')"/> produce 1.0. I just do not understand why my previous test fails (may be due to cache )

Comment: It seems that solr 5.1 use XSLT1.0, there is a feature request : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3058

Comment: @clood, In case solr uses XSLT 1.0 as you said in your comment, then it seems a strange decision to accept the answer that uses XPath 2.0 (and that means XSLT 2.0).   ????   Be aware that even in case you can use an XSLT 2.0 processor, the currently accepted answer still isn't the best solution regarding code quality and completeness. It simply produces an error when applied on the XML document used in my answer.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev, thank you a lot for your answers. As i said at the end of my post, i have upgraded solr to use XSLT 2.0. I do not understand XSLT syntax quite well and since I did not get how to adapt your solution to my context, I used the solution that work straight ahead. In fact the best  solution would be the one using "instance of", because any other solution may produces wrong outputs sometimes depending on the content of the fields.

Comment: @clood, instance of returns false -- because in the absence of a schema, the type of a text node is assumed to be (simply said) string, and a string is not instance of xs:integer. just apply this transformation: `<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  
 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:sequence select=". instance of xs:integer"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>` to this XML document: `<t>5</t>`  -- and you can see that the result is `false`

Comment: @clood, Also, apply this transformation: `<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  
 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:sequence select="number(.) = ."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>` on this XML document: `<t>X</t>` You can see that this produces an error: *Error on line 5 of marrowtr.xsl:
  FORG0001: Cannot convert string "X" to a double
  in built-in template rule
Transformation failed: Run-time errors were reported*  And this is exactly what the code of the accepted answer does...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your goal is to achieve syntactically correct JSON data: no quotes for numbers and the strings "true" and "false". That's what your attempt handling these data types tells me.

In this case the following `xsl:choose` part should work - at least I hope so, since we don't know your input data:

**XSLT-2.0:** (*)

```
  <xsl:choose>
      <!-- if number, do not add quotes -->
      <xsl:when test="number(.)">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:when>
      <!-- if boolean, do not add quotes -->
      <xsl:when test="matches(.,'true|false','i')">
          <xsl:value-of select="lower-case(.)"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>"</xsl:text>          
      </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
```

It should be mentioned (see comments) that all *numbers* get printed without quotation marks. Not only *integers*. Which should be ok for a valid JSON output.

(*) the first version of my answer had a remarkable amount of errors in it which I apologize for (downvoting that answer was quite appropriate). The version shown above has been tested with Saxon and worked as expected.

Comment: This intentionally is an XSLT 2.0 solution as OP himself uses a `version="2.0"` stylesheet. Wrong guess?

Comment: "*OP himself uses a version="2.0" stylesheet.*"  That doesn't mean anything. The fact is that the stylesheet produces an error. I cannot tell if it's because the processor only supports XSLT 1.0, but I believe it's a good guess.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is how to achieve in XSLT 1.0 the intended behavior of the provided XSLT  2.0 code**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match=
  "*[not(*) and text() 
  and 
    not(contains('|true|false|', concat('|', ., '|')))]">
   <xsl:value-of select='concat(&apos;&quot;&apos;, ., &apos;&quot;&apos;)'/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[not(*) and text() and number(.) = .]" priority="3">
   <xsl:value-of select="number(.)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<t>
 <a>1</a>
 <b>true</b>
 <c>false</c>
 <d>-3</d>
 <e>x</e>
 <f>.25</f>
</t>
```

**The wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
 1
 true
 false
 -3
 "x"
 0.25
```

**Do note**: In addition to the behavior that is intended in the provided XSLT 2.0 code, the above transformation also implements correct output of JSON-acceptable representation for any decimal number.

In case only processing and displaying integer values is wanted, just use:

```
floor(.) = .
```

---

**Update**:

The OP has just revealed that he could actually use an XSLT 2.0 processor.

Here is one possible XSLT 2.0 solution, which represents correctly the strings `"true"` and `"false"` as JSON Booleans, any integers and decimals to JSON numbers, and any other atomic value -- to quoted string:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match=
  "*[not(*) and text() and not(. = ('true', 'false'))]">
   <xsl:value-of select='concat(&apos;&quot;&apos;, ., &apos;&quot;&apos;)'/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[not(*) and text() and . castable as xs:decimal]" priority="3">
   <xsl:value-of select="number(.)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above, the same correct, wanted result is produced**:

```
 1
 true
 false
 -3
 "x"
 0.25
```